# ArrayList and Loop

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> gradeN = new ArrayList<String>();
gradeN.add("one");
gradeN.add("two");
int num2 = 0;
while (num<5){
    gradeN.get(0).concat("*");
    num2++;
}
System.out.println(gradeN.get(0));
```

This is not working.
I  want output like this:

```
 one*****
```

and do this in a loop..

Comment: Can you post your expected output? See the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to get the value of `gradeN.get(0)` on every loop and append `*` to it.

i.e.:

```
int num2 = 0;
while (num2<5){
 gradeN.set(0, gradeN.get(0)+"*");
num2++;}
```

---

Output:

```
one*****
```

---

Demo:

http://ideone.com/XQvWqX

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes in your code:

1. The variable incremented in your while loop is different to the one used in the condition.
2. `String`s are immutable. [`String.concat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat-java.lang.String-) returns a **different** `String` object and **does not modify** the original `String`. That means the value in your `List` is not modified. To fix this, use [`List.set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) to replace the old value in the list with a new one.

   ```
   int num2 = 0;
   while (num2 < 5) {
       String newValue = gradeN.get(0).concat("*");
       gradeN.set(0, newValue);
       num2++;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear. Do you always want to add 5 stars to the string? If so, a constant string with 5 stars in it makes more sense than a loop. And I assume you really meant to do this for every element of `gradeN`? So something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> gradeN = new ArrayList<String>();
gradeN.add("one");
gradeN.add("two");

for (int i = 0; i < gradeN.size(); i++) {
    gradeN.set(i, gradeN.get(i) + "*****");
    System.out.println(gradeN.get(i));
}
```

If the number of stars added may vary and you really wanted to append them in a loop, then you could use StringBuilder to build it up:

```
ArrayList<String> gradeN = new ArrayList<String>();
gradeN.add("one");
gradeN.add("two");

int num = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < gradeN.size(); i++) {
    StringBuilder stars = new StringBuilder(gradeN.get(i));
    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        stars.append('*');
    } 
    gradeN.set(i, stars.toString());
    System.out.println(gradeN.get(i));
}
```